# Can video-intelligence-api send the output to a pub/sub topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, video-intelligence-api

Is it possible to have the Video Intelligence API respond on a pub/sub topic? It makes no sense to have a cloud function (or something else) waiting for minutes until the video processing operation completes.

The documentation says you can specify an output_uri for the bucket location and have a topic on that specific bucket, but that may add extra delay.
Also the longrunning package mentions something generic on managing operations on Pub/Sub.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `outputUri`, as you already mentioned, as described in [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/reference/rest/v1/videos/annotate). Now, Google Cloud Storage provides option to [send notifications](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications) about object changes/inserts/deletions to PubSub topic. It's easy to setup, then your downstream app is just plug-and-play on PubSub topic with all info required.

Comment: Yes, I got that. It's too bad though that the output isn't put directly on the pub/sub. On the input side you can base64 the video directly into the API so together with this you could get a response without going through storage...